# PHP - REG_BADBR error when using ereg() for regexp

Tags: php, regex, posix-ere

I have this piece of code for email verification :

```
function VerifRegisterEmail(&$email) {

  if(empty($email)) {

    return false;
  }

  $pattern_email = '^[[:alnum:]\.-_]+@[[:alnum:]\.-_]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2, 3}$';
  if(!ereg('^[[:alnum:]\.-_]+@[[:alnum:]\.-_]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2, 3}$', $email)) {
   echo "emaill";
    return false;
  }


  return true;
}
```

From this i get this error:

```
Warning: ereg() [function.ereg]: REG_BADBR in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\polydotnet\controler\verif_formulaire.php on line 35
emaill- Email incorrecte
```

Any clue ?

Thx

Comment: Use preg_match() instead of ereg(), and don't use regex to validate email addresses.

Comment: I agree with Frank. If you need to validate an email address, `preg_match('/.+@.+/', $email)` is good enough.

Comment: Why ? Is there a better method for checking email addresses ?

Comment: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-September/404146.html

Coders have written thousands of email regexes, and almost all of them fail to conform to RFC 2822.  Fully RFC 2822 compliant regexes have been written, mind you -- but they're thousands of characters long.

Your regex fails for many simple test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space in {2, 3} is causing the problem. Make it {2,3}. Silly, I know.